# How to Iterate over several directory levels and move files based on condition

Tags: python, loops, directory, subdirectory

I would like some help to loop through some directories and subdirectories and extracting data. I have a directory with three levels, with the third level containing several .csv.gz files. The structure is like this

[image: Directory structure example]

I need to access level 2 (where subfolders are) of each folder and check the existence of a specific folder (in my example, this will be subfolder 3; I left the other folders empty for this example, but in real cases they will have data). If checking returns True, then I want to change the name of files within the target subfolder3 and transfer all files to another folder.

Bellow is my code. It is quite cumbersome and there is probably better ways of doing it. I tried using os.walk() and this is the closest I got to a solution but it won't move the files.

```
import os
import shutil
    
    
def organizer(parent_dir, target_dir, destination_dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_dir):
        if root.endswith(target_dir):
            target = root
            for files in os.listdir(target):
                if not files.startswith("."):

                    # this is to change the name of the file
                    fullname = files.split(".")
                    just_name = fullname[0]
                    csv_extension = fullname[1]
                    gz_extension = fullname[2]
                    subject_id = target
                
                    #make a new name
                    origin = subject_id + "/"+ just_name + "." + csv_extension + "." + gz_extension
                
                
                    #make a path based on this new name
                    new_name = os.path.join(destination_dir, origin)
                
                    #move file from origin folder to destination folder and rename the file
                    shutil.move(origin, new_name)
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work and / or more eficient?

Comment: I suppose you might want `os.walk` to avoid 3 nested loops

Comment: Hey, @SitiSchu, I just edited my question to use os.walk. Still, there is something missing here.

Answer (score 0):

simply enough, you can use the built-in os module, with os.walk(path) returns you root directories and files found

```py
import os

for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
    #your code here
```

for your problem, do this

```py
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_directory);
    for file in files:
        #exctract the data from the "file"
```

check this for more information [os.walk()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)

and if you want to get the name of the file, you can use os.path.basename(path)

you can even check for just the gzipped csv files you're looking for using  built-in fnmatch module

```py
import fnmathch, os
def find_csv_files(path):
    result = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, "*.csv.gz"): # find csv.gz using regex paterns
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return list(set(results)) #to get the unique paths if for some reason duplicated
```

Comment: Hello, @Abdulralhman, I have just edited my question because I almost found a solution with os.walk(). However, I still can't move the files. One thing to note is that I need to extract only files from certain folders, so I guess I would have to add that conditional to your solution.

Comment: Also, I am having trouble renaming and moving the file to the destination folder. This means your solution only helps me partially.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, I was finally able to find a solution. Here it is. Not the cleanest one, but it works in my case. Thanks for the help.

```
def organizer(parent_dir, target_dir, destination_dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_dir):
        if root.endswith(target_dir):
            target = root
            for files in os.listdir(target):
                #this one because I have several .DS store files in the folder which I don't want to extract
                if not files.startswith("."):
                    fullname = files.split(".")
                    just_name = fullname[0]
                    csv_extension = fullname[1]
                    gz_extension = fullname[2]
                    
                    origin = target + "/" + files
                    
                    full_folder_name = origin.split("/")

                    #make a new name
                    new_name = full_folder_name[5] + "_"+ just_name + "." + csv_extension + "." + gz_extension
                    
                    #make a path based on this new name
                    new_path = os.path.join(destination_dir, new_name)
                    
                    #move file from origin folder to destination folder and rename the file
                    shutil.move(origin, new_path)
```

The guess the problem was that was passing a variable that was a renamed file (in my example, I wrongly called this variable origin) as the origin path to shutil.move(). Since this path does not exist, then the files weren't moved.